# add html along with images on fancybox

Tags: html, image, text, fancybox

Is it possible to add an HTML description or text underneath the image on Fancybox?

Here is a mock up of what I'm talking about:

[image: Mock up]

If it's not possible, do you know of any plugin that can do this?

Please help

Comment: Check http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#useful No.2 for different options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why yes it's possible
Here's the HTML you'd need to add after you add the image:

```
<div class="fancybox-title fancybox-title-float-wrap">
    <span class="child">
        <div>HI add the html here or delete the div and add the html here</div>
    </span>
</div>
```

To test this out for yourself go ahead to this place: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/ and do some right-click element inspecting.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a fancybox user, but i can suggest you **[ShadowBox](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/)**.

```
<a href="http://www.ancestry.com/wiki/images/archive/a/a9/20100708215937!Example.jpg" rel="shadowbox;height=200;width=200" title="<b>My Image</b><span>Desc</span>">My Image</a>​

#sb-title, #sb-title-inner {height: 3em;}
#sb-title-inner b {display: block; font-size: 1.2em;}
#sb-title-inner span {display: block;}​
```

Fiddle  **[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bagFr/11/)**

Hope this helps